# how to get original value from hash value in node.js

Tags: node.js, md5

I have created hash of some fields and storing in database using 'crypto' npm.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var hashFirtName = crypto.createHash('md5').update(orgFirtName).digest("hex"),
```

QUESTION: How can I get the original value from the hash value when needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [basic definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) of a "hash" is that it's one-way.  You cannot get the originating value from the hash.  Mostly because a single value will always produce the same hash, but a hash isn't always related to a single value, since most hash functions return a string of finite/fixed length.

**Additional Information**

I wanted to provide some additional information, as I felt I may have left this too short.

As @xShirase pointed out in his answer, you can use a table to reverse a Hash.  These are known as [Rainbow Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).  You can generate them or download them from the internet, usually from nefarious sources [ahem].

To expand on my other statement about a hash value possibly relating to multiple original values, lets take a look at MD5.

MD5 is a 128-bit hash.  This means it can hold 2^128 bits, or (unsigned) 0 through 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,455.  That's a REALLY big number.  So, for any given input you have a 1 in 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456 chance that it will collide with the same hash result of another input value.

Now, for simple data like passwords, the chances are astronomical.  And for those purposes, who cares?  Most of the time you are simply taking an input, hashing it, then comparing the hashes.  For reasons I will not get into, when using hashes for passwords you should ALWAYS store the data already hashed.  You don't want to leave plain-text passwords just lying about.  Keep in mind that a hash is ***NOT*** the same as encryption.

Hashes can also be used for other reasons.  For instance, they can be used to create a fast-lookup data structure known as a [Hash Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).  A Hash Table uses a hash as sort of a "primary key", allowing it to search a huge set of data in relatively few number of instructions, approaching O(1) (On-order of 1).  Depending on the implementation of the Hash Table and the hashing algorithm, you have to deal with collisions, usually by means of a sorted list.  This is why the Hash Table isn't "exactly" O(1), but close.  If your hash algorithm is bad, the performance of your Hash Table can begin to approach O(n).

Another use for a hash it to tell if a file's contents have been altered, or match an original.  You will see many OSS project provide binary downloads that also have an MD5 and/or SHA-2 hash values.  This is so you can download the files, do a hash locally, and compare the results against theirs to make sure the file you are getting is the file they posted.  Again, since the odds of two files matching another is 1 in 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456, the odds of a hacker successfully generating a file of the same size with a bad payload that hashes to the exact same MD5/SHA-2 hash is pretty low.

Hope this discussion can help either you or someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you could get the original value from the hash, it wouldn't be that secure.

If you need to compare a value to what you have previously stored as a hash, you can create a hash for this value and compare the hashes.

In practice there is only one way to 'decrypt' a hash. It involves using a massive database of decrypted hashes, and compare them to yours. [An example here](http://www.hashkiller.co.uk/)